# How to replace search box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So here is my site: http://dll-download.us/

I want it where if someone clicks on "Can't Find a File?", I want it to instead select the search box so they can search for it instead.

Code of search box on my site:

```
<form method="get" action="/search" id="search">
  <input name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search for a DLL" />
</form>
```

Comment: what you are asking ?

Comment: You need to look into using javascript to manipulate the DOM. There are some great libraries out there for this purpose, notably jQuery.

Comment: You can add a pop-up search box while clicking that link

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this would be to add a click event to the can't find a file link, then use JavaScript to focus the text box.

```
function setFocus() {
    document.getElementById("myTextbox").focus();
}
```